# javascript how to save data which is checked in checkbox

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble to create a button which can detect which checkbox in the row is checked and save data for the checked row.

For example, if I checked the checkbox for row 1&3 in the project below and press the save all button then the input 1&3 should appear number inside.

```js
function save() {
  document.getElementById(1).value = 1;
}

function save2() {
  document.getElementById(2).value = 2;
}

function save3() {
  document.getElementById(3).value = 3;
}

function saveall() {
  //save the input wherever the checkbox is checked
}
```

```html
<table class="table" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Input</th>
      <th><input id="1"></th>
      <th><input type="checkbox"></th>
      <th><button type="submit" onclick="save()">save</button></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Input</th>
      <th><input id="2"></th>
      <th><input type="checkbox"></th>
      <th><button onclick="save2()">save</button></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Input</th>
      <th><input id="3"></th>
      <th><input type="checkbox"></th>
      <th><button onclick="save3()">save</button></th>
    </tr>
    <button onclick="saveall()">save all</button>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Can I recommend using `function save(number) { document.getElementById(number).value = number; }`

Comment: since HTML5 ids can indeed be single digit strings, but this is bad practice. You have to give a little more meaning to your ids

Comment: you don't need to use a submit type button. They are only useful for forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just implemented the function `saveall()` by:

- searching for a checked checkboxes;
- for each checkbox, searching for a button on the same parent node, and click on it;

As suggested on other comments, you should improve your code:

- Your html is not correct. You are using `thead`, but this is the table body;
- You cannot put a strange tag directly on the `table` (like the `button` of saveAll);
- The ID's should not starts with numbers;
- The multiple functions `save()`, `save1()`, etc., can be `save(inputNumber)`;

```js
function save() {
  document.getElementById(1).value = 1;
}

function save2() {
  document.getElementById(2).value = 2;
}

function save3() {
  document.getElementById(3).value = 3;
}

function saveall() {
  //save the input wherever the checkbox is checked
  let nodeList = document.querySelectorAll('input:checked');
  nodeList.forEach(node => node.parentNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll('button')[0].click());
}
```

```html
<table class="table" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Input</th>
      <th><input id="1"></th>
      <th><input type="checkbox"></th>
      <th><button type="submit" onclick="save()">save</button></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Input</th>
      <th><input id="2"></th>
      <th><input type="checkbox"></th>
      <th><button onclick="save2()">save</button></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Input</th>
      <th><input id="3"></th>
      <th><input type="checkbox"></th>
      <th><button onclick="save3()">save</button></th>
    </tr>
    <button onclick="saveall()">save all</button>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `id` for each checkbox like you did for each regular input bar

```js
function save(n) {
  document.getElementById(n).value = n;
}
let checkbox1=document.getElementById('ch1')
let checkbox2=document.getElementById('ch2')
let checkbox3=document.getElementById('ch3')

function saveall() {
  if(checkbox1.checked){document.getElementById(1).value=1}
  if(checkbox2.checked){document.getElementById(2).value=2}
  if(checkbox3.checked){document.getElementById(3).value=3}
}
```

```html
<table class="table" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Input</th>
      <th><input id="1"></th>
      <th><input id="ch1" type="checkbox"></th>
      <th><button type="submit" onclick="save(1)">save</button></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Input</th>
      <th><input id="2"></th>
      <th><input id="ch2" type="checkbox"></th>
      <th><button onclick="save(2)">save</button></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Input</th>
      <th><input id="3"></th>
      <th><input id="ch3" type="checkbox"></th>
      <th><button onclick="save(3)">save</button></th>
    </tr>
    <button onclick="saveall()">save all</button>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this as well.

```js
function save(n) {
    let el = document.getElementById(n);
    if(document.getElementById(`ch${n}`).checked)
        el.value = n;
    else
        el.value = "";
}

function saveall() {
    document.querySelectorAll(".table input[type='checkbox'][id^='ch']").forEach(function(el){
        let id = el.attributes.id.value;
        let input_id = id.substring(2, id.length);

        if(el.checked)
            document.getElementById(input_id).value = input_id;
        else
            document.getElementById(input_id).value = "";
    })
}
```

```html
<table class="table" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Input</th>
      <th><input id="1"></th>
      <th><input id="ch1" type="checkbox"></th>
      <th><button type="submit" onclick="save(1)">save</button></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Input</th>
      <th><input id="2"></th>
      <th><input id="ch2" type="checkbox"></th>
      <th><button onclick="save(2)">save</button></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Input</th>
      <th><input id="3"></th>
      <th><input id="ch3" type="checkbox"></th>
      <th><button onclick="save(3)">save</button></th>
    </tr>
    <button onclick="saveall()">save all</button>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
 localStorage.setItem("", JSON.stringify())
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("", JSON.stringify()
event.preventdefault()
variable = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("")) || [];
```

the first line will send your data to local storage
the second line will get it
the third line to prevent default
forth line for preventing null

Comment: Your comment explain your code, but this doesn't answer to this question!